# AngularJS Search Change Event

Tags: search, angularjs

I need an event like `$routeChangeSuccess` but for the $location.search() variable. I am calling $location.search('newview'), and need a way to know when it changes.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs $watch on $location.search doesn't work when reloadOnSearch is false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093916/angularjs-watch-on-location-search-doesnt-work-when-reloadonsearch-is-false)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `$scope.$watch`:

```js
$scope.$watch(function(){ return $location.search() }, function(){
  // reaction
});
```

See more about `$watch` in Angular [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope).

If you are just looking for the addition of 'newview', to the query string the above code will work.

> i.e. from `http://server/page` to `http://server/page?newvalue`

However, if you are looking for a change in 'newview' the above code will not work.

> i.e from `http://server/page?newvalue=a` to `http://server/page?newvalue=b`

You will need to use the 'objectEquality' param to the call to $watch.  This causes $watch to use value equality, instead of object reference equality.

```js
$scope.$watch(function(){ return $location.search() }, function(){
  // reaction
}, true);
```

Notice the addition of 3rd param (true).

Comment: Ah, you can actually use a function in watch. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you use the "objectEquality" param (3rd argument) in the call to $watch.  Without this, it checks for object reference equality, not by value.  The $watch would works if 'newview' was added to the querystring, but would not work if you changed the value of 'newview'

Comment: couldn't you just do: $scope.watch($location.search, function() { ... })

Comment: No, you couldn't. The first argument in $watch function is called with the $scope as first argument and the $location.search method, in this case, expect no argument

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for $routeUpdate event in your controller:

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(){
   $scope.sort = $location.search().sort;
   $scope.order = $location.search().order;
   $scope.offset = $location.search().offset;
});
```